# iOS7 unexpected result with responsive fixed menu

Tags: css, html, position, ios7, fixed

i have a problem with a site i created recently ([www.ppdcstudio.com](http://www.ppdcstudio.com)), but only now found a problem with iOS7 (still works as expected with desktop and previous versions of iOS).

I have a position:fixed top bar (logo and menu) that has responsive width. the logo is kept on the left and the menu on the right. when resizing the browser they get close together and the menu collapses and you get a html-select kind of menu (actually it is a block with hidden li's).

The problem it self is that in iOS7 it doesn't show the menu at all, and the pages are all messed up.

(i think the menu is there, but i can't scroll to see it cuz of position fixed)

I used this as a fix for devices when first made the site but now i think this might be what's causing the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=0.75,user-scalable=yes" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;">
```

any advice?
thanks

Comment: Mobiles are notorious for having issue with fixed positioning. Many mobile browsers don't support it. Not sure about iOS7 though.